# Format of InstallationTemplate.Expiry property in Notification Hub .NET server API?

Tags: .net, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I am using the server-side .NET API for Azure Notification Hub. I want to use the new installation model mentioned in [this blog post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn948105.aspx) and I want to take advantage of [templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/azure/dn530748.aspx) to keep the platform-specific code out of my server code.

This means that I want to instantiate an instance of [InstallationTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.installationtemplate.aspx). But the [Expiry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.installationtemplate.expiry.aspx#P:Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.InstallationTemplate.Expiry) property is a String and I have no idea what format ANH expects for it. As far as I can glance from the [APNS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW4), this property ends up in a binary encoded integer representing the number of seconds from the UNIX epoch. So no help there.

What is the format to use for InstallationTemplate.Expiry?

Answer (score 0):

Any string parsable as DateTime in .Net will work, so someDate.ToString() should be OK.

Comment: Did you find any documentation for this or was it the result of experiments?

Answer (score 0):

The [REST API documentation for ANH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621153.aspx) states the following for the expiry:

> Template expression evaluating in W3D date format.

I assume it should be [W3C date format](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:c8_7g58tkVAJ:www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime+&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de) as there is no W3D date format, and therefore should be this:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss
```